# Connect to an Oracle database

Tags: c#, database, oracle11g, database-connection

I'm trying to connect to an Oracle database but when the the code is executing the line:

```
con = new OracleConnection(oradb);
```

It gives this error. "The program can't start because oraons.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem." I installed the ODP for .net on my computer already from the following site http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-085163.html and referenced the Oracle.DataAccess.

I also checked the folder that was installed and I can see the oraons dll in the folder. Here's the code:

```
class OracleDatabase
{
    OracleConnection con;
    public void ConnectToOracleDb()
    {
        string oradb = getConnectionString("host", 1521, "sid", "user", "pass");

        try
        {
            con = new OracleConnection(oradb);
            con.Open();
            Console.WriteLine("Connected to Oracle" + con.ServerVersion);
        }
        catch
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Could not connect to FLX");
        }

    }

    private static string getConnectionString(string databaseIP, int databasePort, string databaseSID, string databaseUN, string databasePW)
    {
        return string.Format(
            "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = {0})(PORT = {1}))(CONNECT_DATA =(SID = {2})));" +
            "Persist Security Info=True;User ID={3};Password={4}",
            databaseIP, databasePort, databaseSID, databaseUN, databasePW
        );
    }
}
```

Why can't I connect any suggestions?

Comment: if you used Oracle xcopy(seems that way) to install the ODP.NET drivers, check if the drivers directory has been added to to the Windows system PATH. In case of Oracle xcopy, you have to do it manually.

Comment: Just checked it's been added already @NicholasKrasnov

Comment: did you install the oracle client software?

Comment: I ran into the same problem with unmanaged oracle on win server 2008, but it worked fine on win server 2008 R2. In either case, I have the proper path to oracle home in my path environment variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ended up referencing the ManagedDataAccess.Client instead of just the Data.Access.Client one and it worked.

Comment: The problem was the PATH. Choosing Managed Data Access was cheating :)

Answer (score 7):

The PATH setting is not necessary. I solved the same issue with a copy of the `oraons.dll` into dhe `ORACLE_HOME\bin` folder and after that the installation works.

There is a difference between an Oracle setup via installer and the xcopy depoyment. I don't now why. Both installations had the same registry setting:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Oracle\ODP.NET\4.112.4.0\DllPath
```

and the `DllPath` points to the `BIN` folder of the `ORACLE_HOME`. That means a PATH setting to the `BIN` folder of the `ORACLE_HOME` does not help. An additional `PATH` to the `ORACLE_HOME` of the client would help. I think that is not necessary. Only a copy of the `oraons.dll` into the `BIN` is enough.

Answer (score 4):

I was getting that error in my test project. The problem was that I was opening Visual Studio from a command line that had an old PATH. After opening everything fresh, it worked.

Check the PATH from your code, and make sure the oracle folder is in the PATH.

Comment: Thank you.  Ran into this problem today.   Started from the windows menu instead of slick run and this fixed the issue

Comment: Actually I installed the driver whilst VS was running. Reopening of VS helped, thx!