# Visual Studio 2012. ---> System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'OraOps12.dll': The specified module could not be found

Tags: c#, oracle, visual-studio-2012, dll, odp.net

I imported a C# project in Visual Studio 2012. It has a reference to Oracle.DataAccess. When I run the project, i get an exception. Here's what I could get from debugging.

```
ex = {System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection' threw an exception. --->
```

System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'OraOps12.dll': 
The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESU...

I don't know where it is looking for this DLL. I have ODT installed. The Oracle.DataAccess.dll file to which the reference is made is in:

E:\app\client\serban.stoenescu\product\12.1.0\client_1\odp.net\bin\4.

The OraOps12.dll file is in:

E:\app\client\serban.stoenescu\product\12.1.0\client_1\bin

Any idea what's going on? How do I find out where the program is looking for this DLL? Any idea if I can find out if there is a nested exception?

Thanks,
Serban

Comment: Are you sure that Oracle Client is installed on the machine where Visual Studio runs?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could try using Sysinternals Process Monitor, it might give you some insight ?

It looks like you have installed ODP.NET, perhaps you need to install: Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package (x64) or (x86).

[Process Monitor showing missing MSVCR100.dll](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HLk7H.png)

If you get past this and see a NullReferenceException on OracleConnection.Open() then you will need to set a path to your client (where oraons.dll lives, see 
[Connect to an Oracle database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21863682/connect-to-an-oracle-database))

Answer (score 0):

Make sure Oracle client is installed. Oracle Dll comes in 32 bit and 64 bit version. so make sure the correct version of the file is used in the project.